How to use CriteriaBuilder to work with a MonthDay that has been persisted as a varchar?
I have some java.time objects that are persisted as varchars and that I want to create predicates for using the Criteria API .
It works perfectly fine for LocalDate (Hibernate does a cast to date in this case).
criteriaBuilder.between(root.get("my_varchar_column_that_contains_a_date").as(LocalDate.class), startLocalDate, endLocalDate)

The same code for MonthDay makes Hibernate cast to bytea and the predicate does not work.
criteriaBuilder.between(root.get("my_varchar_column_that_contains_a_monthday").as(MonthDay.class), startMonthDay, endMonthDay)

I am unsure how to debug this any further and whether it's possible at all.
For Year I can cast to Integer as a workaround which works well.
criteriaBuilder.between(root.get("my_varchar_column_that_contains_a_year").as(Integer.class), startYear.getValue(),endYear.getValue())

Is there a possible way to work with actual MonthDay objects or is resorting to a string-based comparison the only option?
I'm using Hibernate 5.6.10, Spring Data 2.7.1 and Postgres 13.15.
